# Is there any way to use jlink in IntelliJ IDEA to create a custom modular run-time image?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-platform-module-system, jlink

I'm following the [Project Jigsaw: Module System Quick-Start Guide](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5. I did everything right in the IDE until [The linker](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#linker) section. **Is there any way to use jlink in IntelliJ IDEA?**

> *jlink (see [JEP 282](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282)) is the linker tool and can be used to link a set of modules, along with their transitive dependences, to create a custom modular run-time image (see [JEP 220](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220)).*
>   <sub><sub>- Project Jigsaw: Module System Quick-Start Guide</sub></sub>

I found this [Ability to produce JLink artefacts](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161641) issue in *JetBrains Bug & Issue Tracker*, but it has been open for more than 2 years and it doesn't even have a description.

---

As a workaround, I have seen this [Is there a maven jigsaw jlink plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360572/is-there-a-maven-jigsaw-jlink-plugin) interesting question and the most promising alternative seems to be the [Apache Maven JLink Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jlink-plugin/), but it has also been there for more than 2 years and it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Since you've linked to one of the questions I'd answered(updated there as well). Did you give [`maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-jlink-plugin/3.0.0-alpha-1/maven-plugin) a try? Feedback is a crucial aspect before moving that to releases I believe. The blog linked in the answer there should help you with the process.

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer. I didn't really try the plugin (yet), I'm just starting to try the new Java features since version 9. The question is **how to use jlink in IntelliJ IDEA**, I just thought of Maven as an alternative within the IDE and I was disappointed not to find a stable solution. Even according to documentation, the current version of this plugin requires JDK 9, when the latest version is 11.

Comment: The exact question of *using jlink via IntelliJ* seems to have been answered by the links you've shared in the question to me (we can wait for a contributor of IntelliJ to actually confirm.)  Regarding the plugin you can track the updates in the actual [source repository and contribute](https://github.com/apache/maven-jlink-plugin#contributing-to-apache-maven-jlink-plugin) further.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ant as a build tool and specify your own jlink target, like this:

```
<target name="link">
    <echo message="Creating jlink image in directory = dist\bin\java" />
    <exec executable="jlink">
        <arg line='--module-path bin;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1-Linux\jmods";"C:\Users\VTorroni\_libs\hsqldb-2.4.1\modules";"C:\Users\VTorroni\_libs\tinylog-1.3.5\module";"C:\Users\VTorroni\_libs\javax.servlet-api-4.0.1\module\javax.servlet.api-4.0.1.jar" --add-modules pnode --output dist\bin\java --strip-debug --no-header-files --no-man-pages --compress=2' />
    </exec>
</target>
```